# How does paintComponent work?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

This might be a very noob question. I'm just starting to learn Java

I don't understand the operation of paintComponent method. I know if I want to draw something, I must override the paintComponent method.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
   ...
}
```

But when is it called? I never see anything like "object.paintComponent(g)" but still it is drawn when the program is running.

And what is the Graphics parameter? Where is it from? Parameter must be supplied when the method is called. But as I said before, it seems like this method is never be explicitly called. So who provides this parameter? And why do we have to cast it to Graphics2D?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    ...
    Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Start with [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Comment: @trashgod is always so kind to post a concrete link - which also is referenced in the [swing tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) :-) Or in other words: always look into the wiki first ...

Comment: @kleopatra: +1 Also easier to fix in the next (inevitable) link extinction.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The (very) short answer to your question is that `paintComponent` is called "when it needs to be."  Sometimes it's easier to think of the Java Swing GUI system as a "black-box," where much of the internals are handled without too much visibility.

There are a number of factors that determine when a component needs to be re-painted, ranging from moving, re-sizing, changing focus, being hidden by other frames, and so on and so forth.  Many of these events are detected auto-magically, and `paintComponent` is called internally when it is determined that that operation is necessary.

I've worked with Swing for many years, and I don't think I've **ever** called `paintComponent` directly, or even seen it called directly from something else.  The closest I've come is using the `repaint()` methods to programmatically trigger a repaint of certain components (which I assume calls the correct `paintComponent` methods downstream.

In my experience, `paintComponent` is rarely directly overridden.  I admit that there are custom rendering tasks that require such granularity, but Java Swing does offer a (fairly) robust set of JComponents and Layouts that can be used to do much of the heavy lifting without having to directly override `paintComponent`.  I guess my point here is to make sure that you can't do something with native JComponents and Layouts before you go off trying to roll your own custom-rendered components.

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumePolet for catching that.  My terms were technically incorrect there, just as you stated.  I've edited the post to clarify.

Comment: SeKa, since you have worked with swing for many years, do you mind if I ask, is swing/javafx something worth learning from a student/job seeker prospective? is swing/javafx used a lot? Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 17):

Two things you can do here:

1. Read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
2. Use a debugger and put a breakpoint in the paintComponent method. Then travel up the stacktrace and see how provides the Graphics parameter.

Just for info, here is the stacktrace that I got from the example of code I posted at the end:

```
Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 15 in TestPaint))  
    TestPaint.paintComponent(Graphics) line: 15 
    TestPaint(JComponent).paint(Graphics) line: 1054    
    JPanel(JComponent).paintChildren(Graphics) line: 887    
    JPanel(JComponent).paint(Graphics) line: 1063   
    JLayeredPane(JComponent).paintChildren(Graphics) line: 887  
    JLayeredPane(JComponent).paint(Graphics) line: 1063 
    JLayeredPane.paint(Graphics) line: 585  
    JRootPane(JComponent).paintChildren(Graphics) line: 887 
    JRootPane(JComponent).paintToOffscreen(Graphics, int, int, int, int, int, int) line: 5228   
    RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(JComponent, Image, Graphics, int, int, int, int) line: 1482 
    RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(JComponent, JComponent, Graphics, int, int, int, int) line: 1413  
    RepaintManager.paint(JComponent, JComponent, Graphics, int, int, int, int) line: 1206   
    JRootPane(JComponent).paint(Graphics) line: 1040    
    GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Component, Graphics) line: 39    
    GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback(SunGraphicsCallback).runOneComponent(Component, Rectangle, Graphics, Shape, int) line: 78    
    GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback(SunGraphicsCallback).runComponents(Component[], Graphics, int) line: 115 
    JFrame(Container).paint(Graphics) line: 1967    
    JFrame(Window).paint(Graphics) line: 3867   
    RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Map<Component,Rectangle>) line: 781    
    RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions() line: 728    
    RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions() line: 677 
    RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager) line: 59  
    RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run() line: 1621  
    InvocationEvent.dispatch() line: 251    
    EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent, Object) line: 705    
    EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue, AWTEvent, Object) line: 101   
    EventQueue$3.run() line: 666    
    EventQueue$3.run() line: 664    
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]    
    ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext, AccessControlContext) line: 76    
    EventQueue.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 675    
    EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(int) line: 211   
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(int, Conditional, EventFilter) line: 128    
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(int, Conditional, Component) line: 117   
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(int, Conditional) line: 113  
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Conditional) line: 105   
    EventDispatchThread.run() line: 90
```

The Graphics parameter comes from here:

```
RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Map) line: 781
```

The snippet involved is the following:

```
Graphics g = JComponent.safelyGetGraphics(
                        dirtyComponent, dirtyComponent);
                // If the Graphics goes away, it means someone disposed of
                // the window, don't do anything.
                if (g != null) {
                    g.setClip(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
                    try {
                        dirtyComponent.paint(g); // This will eventually call paintComponent()
                    } finally {
                        g.dispose();
                    }
                }
```

If you take a look at it, you will see that it retrieve the graphics from the JComponent itself (indirectly with `javax.swing.JComponent.safelyGetGraphics(Component, Component)`) which itself takes it eventually from its first "Heavyweight parent" (clipped to the component bounds) which it self takes it from its corresponding native resource.

Regarding the fact that you have to cast the `Graphics` to a `Graphics2D`, it just happens that when working with the Window Toolkit, the `Graphics` actually extends `Graphics2D`, yet you could use other `Graphics` which do "not have to" extends `Graphics2D` (it does not happen very often but AWT/Swing allows you to do that).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class TestPaint extends JPanel {

    public TestPaint() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(300, 300);
        jFrame.add(new TestPaint());
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you paint to the JPanel if the TestPaint didn't extend the JPanel class?

Answer (score 3):

The internals of the GUI system call that method, and they pass in the `Graphics` parameter as a graphics context onto which you can draw.

Comment: @nubhihi219 doesn't matter :-) You have no control about when the painting is happening anyway, _internals_ are ... well ... internals, nothing to wory about in application development, except in very rare corner cases

Answer (score 2):

Calling `object.paintComponent(g)` is an error.

Instead this method is called automatically when the panel is created. The `paintComponent()` method can also be called explicitly by the `repaint()` method defined in `Component` class.

The effect of calling `repaint()` is that Swing automatically clears the graphic on the panel and executes the `paintComponent` method to redraw the graphics on this panel.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to redefine the method `void paintComponent(Graphics g){}` if you want any previous drawing to be permanent on a component. You need to do this by calling the ascending class's method explicitly like `super.painComponent();`.  This way, any time java will need to use that paintComponent method you are keeping changes made.

This is explained by the fact that if you don't, the superclass will undo everything you've done by simply calling its own method, totally ignoring any change.