# Java 8/Eclipse Image not visible

Tags: java, eclipse, jpanel, toolkit

I am trying to get an Image for a little animation but the Panel stays white. 
The image is in the same folder than the class.

```
public class JBallonPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
private Image img;
private int x, y;

JBallonPanel(){
    setBackground(Color.white);
    img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(".//Ball.jpg");
    x=this.getWidth()/2;
    y=this.getHeight()/2;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, 
            img.getWidth(this), img.getWidth(this), this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look below, I just did some adjustments, but your code is working.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

    //public class JBallonPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    //You can remove implements Runnable
    public class JBallonPanel extends JPanel {
    private Image img;
    private int x, y;

    JBallonPanel(){
        setBackground(Color.white);
        // your path should have \\ for example C:\\Ball.jpg or C:\\myImageFolder\\Ball.jpg 
        // but in your case, it works too.
        img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("C:\\Ball.jpg");
        x=this.getWidth()/2;
        y=this.getHeight()/2;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, img.getWidth(this), img.getWidth(this),     this);
    }

    //And run like this
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JBallonPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure! After you do your tests, tell me if it's working fine.

Comment: I think you (and OP) are missing `super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: Actually, there is no need to call `super.paintComponent(g)` as this code is working fine. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544549/how-does-paintcomponent-work)  for further information if needed.