# Why is the paintComponent method executed many times?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I found something strange in the paintComponent method. When I put 'System.out.println("1") ; in the paintComponent method, 1 was output Three times in the console window. As far as I've looked into it, the paintComponent method runs many times[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P26w.png). I wonder why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does paintComponent work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544549/how-does-paintcomponent-work)

Comment: nsj247, in general its preferred to include code in your question instead of images of code. You can see some reasons why on this meta answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2754938

Answer (score 0):

`paintComponent` gets run a lot. For example, Every time the JComponent is resized, shown, validated from an invalid state, and when repaint() is called. This functionality exists so that Components can change their display dynamically as things change, rather than being static in display  like an image